# How to choose a common name for different domain patterns

Tags: ssl

The common name for my SSL Key is `.mydomain.com` . What common name should i get issued so that i can use a URL like `https://api.mydomain.com` and `https://api-test.mydomain.com` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wildcard certificate using *.mydomain.com

Comment: is the wildcard SSL the same as simple SSL or do i just add the common name of *.mydomain.com to a simple SSL key ?

Comment: Check with your certificate issuer.  You'll likely need to restart the entire certificate request process which would include purchasing a wildcard cert.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow wildcard ssl and simple domain ssl both are same. For your SSL key concern, the only change you should is common name. Wildcard ssl requires key for *.yourdomain.tld.

PS: All SSL CA requires 2048 bit CSR key.

Here you check how it makes difference and similar.

Technical Difference:

1. Simple ssl and wildcard ssl carry different common name. As explained above.
2. Simple SSL secures only www and non-www domain name. Where wildcard secures unlimited sub-domain names.

Similar terms:

1. Both requires domain control verification process. DCV process is compulsory for everyone to acquire ssl certificate.
2. Both support same technology ssl encryption.
3. Both requires 2048-bit CSR key.